# The number of calendar weeks in a year?

Tags: python, date

In Python, how can we find out the number of calendar weeks in a year?

I didn't find a function in the standard library.

I then thought about `date(year, 12, 31).isocalendar()[1]`, but

> For example, 2004 begins on a Thursday, so the first week of ISO year 2004 begins on Monday, 29 Dec 2003 and ends on Sunday, 4 Jan 2004, so that `date(2003, 12, 29).isocalendar() == (2004, 1, 1)` and `date(2004, 1, 4).isocalendar() == (2004, 1, 7)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the same ISO specification, January 4th is *always* going to be week 1 of a given year. By the same calculation, the 28th of December is then *always* in the last week of the year. You can use that to find the last week number of a given year:

```
from datetime import date

def weeks_for_year(year):
    last_week = date(year, 12, 28)
    return last_week.isocalendar().week
```

Also see Wikipedia, the ISO week article [lists all properties of the last week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week):

> - It has the year's last Thursday in it.
> - It is the last week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in December.
> - Its middle day, Thursday, falls in the ending year.
> - Its last day is the Sunday nearest to 31 December.
> - It has 28 December in it. Hence the latest possible dates are 28 December through 3 January, the earliest 21 through 28 December.

For more comprehensive week calculations, you could use the [`isoweek` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek); it has a `Week.last_week_of_year()` class method:

```
>>> import isoweek
>>> isoweek.Week.last_week_of_year(2014)
isoweek.Week(2014, 52)
>>> isoweek.Week.last_week_of_year(2014).week
52
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, take the date of Dec. 28. If there is a monday after that, it will only have 3 days in the old year and hence be week 1 of the new year.

Answer (score 0):

I think Martijn Pieters has a great solution, the only draw back is you have to install the module which is an overkill if your ONLY use case is getting the week#, here is something you can do without installing any modules. (FYI this was tested for Python 3.8)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
from datetime import timedelta,datetime

#change the your_year to the year you would like to get the last week#
your_year= 2020
# we add 1 to get to the next year !
next_year_date =datetime(your_year+1, 1, 1)
# we subtract 4 days only to go to the last day of previous/your_year 
# this is because of [ISO spec][1]  
last_day = next_year_date - timedelta(days=4)
print(last_day)
# we just get the week count
print(last_day.isocalendar()[1] )
```